# Azure Data Factory - Private Endpoint : Unable to access the Azure Data Factory inside the VNET?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-data-factory, terraform-provider-azure

I am developing a Terraform Script to provision the Azure Data Factory, it works fine without Private Zone & Private Endpoint. As soon as I added the Private Endpoint, I can no longer access the Azure Data Factory within the VNET

[image]

Below is the Terraform script used

```
    // Create a Data Factory
resource "azurerm_data_factory" "datafactory" {
  name                = "ipz10datafactorydemo"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  # public_network_enabled = false

  identity {
    type         = "UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.uai_adf.id]
  }

  github_configuration {
    account_name = "kvija85"
    branch_name = "main"
    git_url = "https://github.com/kvija85/azure-data-factory-etl-demo"
    repository_name = "azure-data-factory-etl-demo"
    root_folder = "/"
  }

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_resource_group.resource_group, azurerm_user_assigned_identity.uai_adf
  ]  
}

// Create Private Endpoint Zone for Azure Data Factory
resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "datafactoryzone" {
  name                = "privatelink.datafactory.azure.net"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_resource_group.resource_group
  ]  
}

// Create Private Endpoint Zone for Azure Data Factory Portal
resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "datafactoryportalzone" {
  name                = "privatelink.adf.azure.com"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_resource_group.resource_group
  ]  
}

// Link the Private Zone to Hub
resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "network_link_hub_vnet_datafactoryzone" {
  name                  = "vnet_link_hub_datafactoryzone"
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.datafactoryzone.name
  virtual_network_id    = azurerm_virtual_network.hub_vnet.id

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_resource_group.resource_group, azurerm_private_dns_zone.datafactoryzone, azurerm_virtual_network.hub_vnet
  ]  
}

// Link the Private Zone to Spoke
resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "network_link_spoke_vnet_datafactoryzone" {
  name                  = "vnet_link_spoke_datafactoryzone"
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.datafactoryzone.name
  virtual_network_id    = azurerm_virtual_network.spoke_vnet.id

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_resource_group.resource_group, azurerm_private_dns_zone.datafactoryzone, azurerm_virtual_network.spoke_vnet
  ]    
}

// Link the Private Zone to Hub
resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "network_link_hub_vnet_datafactoryportalzone" {
  name                  = "vnet_link_hub_datafactoryportalzone"
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.datafactoryportalzone.name
  virtual_network_id    = azurerm_virtual_network.hub_vnet.id

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_resource_group.resource_group, azurerm_private_dns_zone.datafactoryportalzone, azurerm_virtual_network.hub_vnet
  ]  
}

// Link the Private Zone to Spoke
resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "network_link_spoke_vnet_datafactoryportalzone" {
  name                  = "vnet_link_spoke_datafactoryportalzone"
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.datafactoryportalzone.name
  virtual_network_id    = azurerm_virtual_network.spoke_vnet.id

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_resource_group.resource_group, azurerm_private_dns_zone.datafactoryportalzone, azurerm_virtual_network.spoke_vnet
  ]    
}

// Create Private Endpoint for Data Factory
module "pedatafactory" {
    source = "./modules/privateendpoint/"

    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
    location = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.location
    name = var.privateendpointdatafactory_name

    subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.endpoint_subnet.id
    private_link_enabled_resource_id = azurerm_data_factory.datafactory.id
    private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.datafactoryzone.name
    subresource_names = ["dataFactory"]
    resource_name = azurerm_data_factory.datafactory.name

    depends_on = [
      azurerm_data_factory.datafactory, azurerm_private_dns_zone.datafactoryzone
    ]
}

// Create Private Endpoint for Data Factory Portal
module "pedatafactoryportal" {
    source = "./modules/privateendpoint/"

    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
    location = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.location
    name = var.privateendpointdatafactory_portal_name

    subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.endpoint_subnet.id
    private_link_enabled_resource_id = azurerm_data_factory.datafactory.id
    private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.datafactoryportalzone.name
    subresource_names = ["portal"]
    resource_name = azurerm_data_factory.datafactory.name

    depends_on = [
      azurerm_data_factory.datafactory, azurerm_private_dns_zone.datafactoryportalzone
    ]
}
```

What am I missing here? why enabling the private endpoint prevents me from accessing the Azure Data Factory?

As per the [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-private-link#create-the-private-endpoint), I need to configure few more

[image]

However, I am not sure what & how to do this?

Comment: What you could do is manually set it up from the portal, test it, capture it's ARM template. Now repeat with Terraform and capture resulting ARM template and compare. And again I wonder..... why use Terraform for a resource type that only exists in Azure?

Comment: What did you actually change when turned on private endpoint? What kind of NSG/firewall rules do you have for VM running web browser for authoring?

> why enabling the private endpoint prevents me from accessing the Azure Data Factory?
`pedatafactoryportal` changes connection to adf.zure.com and might have some faults.

I would double-check private endpoint DNS templating and if correct entries are created for given private DNS zone and DNS issues on the VM.

Also note that adf.azure.com still works from public internet: it can be used to check if other connection from SHIR are working

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, can you please help me with the manual steps or cli to configure the private endpoint for Azure data factory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

•   Please remember the below point while creating a private endpoint for an Azure Data Factory workspace since it addresses a **limitation** regarding it: -

> Connecting to Data Factory via private endpoint is only applicable to self-hosted IR in Data Factory. It isn't supported for Azure Synapse Analytics

Therefore, similarly, I tried to **`create an integration runtime in Azure Data Factory workspace created and tried to import data into it through Azure blob storage as the source dataset and process it to the Azure SQL Database as the sink dataset wherein the private endpoint connection is created for the Azure storage account as well as the Azure SQL Database also and the data is imported through the private endpoint created for the Azure blob storage in a text format to the ADF and similarly through the data process pipeline created in ADF, the data is forwarded to the Azure SQL Database wherein it is processed based on the query created in the table shown below and the pipeline setup accordingly`**.

Thus, **creating private endpoints for the Azure SQL DB, Azure storage account and the Azure ADF also accordingly in the integration runtime pipeline can be configured and deployed successfully. But the virtual network integration along with the private endpoint created in the private DNS zone is not successful due to an internal bug in the Azure fabric setup as it is giving out a 502 page error for that configuration**.

Please find the below snapshots for more detailed configuration and deployment: -

Azure storage account private endpoint: -

[image: Azure storage account PE]

Azure SQL DB private endpoint: -

[image: Azure SQL DB PE]

Azure ADF private endpoint: -

[image: Azure ADF PE]

Azure ADF Pipeline deployment: -

[image: Azure ADF dataset]
[image: Azure ADF Pipeline]
[image: Azure ADF source dataset]

Thus, in this way, you can **configure the data ingestion and processing pipeline using the Integrated Runtime by using the private endpoints respectively for connection purposes in Azure Data factory**.

For more detailed information regarding this, please refer the below links: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-portal-private***